# Ionic - Using Javascript to define SASS variables

Tags: angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework, sass

I am making a **hybrid ionic phonegap app**.I am using **sass** to define color variables.

As part of my app I need to be able to change the colors depending on what is defined in an external database.

I know how to connect to the server in my controllers to return Json data.

Is there anyway I could connect to the server using HTTP requests in my sass file?

So that it is possible for the **app colors to change depending on what is saved in the database**?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

You should be converting your SCSS to CSS so you have whatever you set.

A way that you can achieve something similar is by utilising SCSS themes. How this works is to simply overwrite all your colour vars with different themes.

```
$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
$red: #e2061c;
$gray-light: #c9c8c8;
$gray: #838282;
$gray-dark: #333333;
$blue: #253652;
```

You could then use angular (or whatever framework you are using) to switch out the style sheet depending on which theme your users have chosen.

Angular -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ng-href="{{user.theme}}.css">
```

SCSS -

Folder structure

```
|- _scss/
|-|- _base/
|-|-|- _config.scss

|-|- _layouts/
|-|-|- _l-grid.scss
|-|-|- _l-default.scss

|-|- _modules/
|-|-|- _m-accordions.scss
|-|-|- _m-teasers.scss

|-|-_themes/
|-|-|- _light-theme/
|-|-|-|- light.scss

|-|- application.scss
```

[This atrical goes into great detail on how to theme your applications](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sass-to-build-one-project-with-multiple-themes--cms-22104)

Comment: thats not quite what im looking for, there are no themes defined but for the given app the admin can chose what colors they would like to use for the app and so these values are saved in an external mysql database. i need it so that the app colors change if the the admin changes the colors to whatever